# Super svelte slots

Tags: svelte, sveltekit, slots

Suposse the next scenario:

./__layout.svelte

```
<script>
  const hi = "hi";
</script>

<h1>{hi}</h1>
<slot />
<slot name="safely" />
```

./index.svelte

```
<h1>
  This is my awesome index page!
</h1>
```

./route/to/something/index.svelte

```
<p>
  in this page we have safely components
</p>

<div slot="safely">
  <CustomComponent>
    first
  </CustomComponent>
</div>
```

./in/another/nested/component/index.svelte

```
<p>
  another safely component
</p>

<div slot="safely">
  <CustomComponent>
    second
  </CustomComponent>
</div>
```

**`on safely slot:`**

```
<CustomComponent>
  first
</CustomComponent>

<CustomComponent>
  second
</CustomComponent>
```

Are there way to do something like this? something like super, or global slots.

Comment: Should the last code block suggest that the layout "collects" all usages of the slot in the directory subtree? If so, this will probably be either impossible or require forking SvelteKit to modify its routing. SvelteKit only looks at ancestors to allow [nesting layouts](https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/layouts#nested-layouts).

Comment: Umm  nested layouts is usefull but is not exactly my case, I wish use something like "zones" to save code blocks from any scope, like a store but using components.

Comment: I was just pointing out the current limitations to traversal from leaf to parents. The question remains whether this is supposed to get content from multiple files at the same time (even though they are not the current route)?

Comment: Exactly, should save content from multiple files at same time.

Comment: That sounds like a bit of a bad idea, even if you get it to work somehow. It makes it hard to intuit where things are coming from, when the content could be from any file in the subtree.

Comment: It's a hard functionality... maybe Im not thinking in a better solution :C

Comment: The idea looks like react portal to me. It could be done with custom action. Reference: [svelte-portal](https://github.com/romkor/svelte-portal/blob/master/src/Portal.svelte)

Comment: @hackape Thank you, svelte-portal is the concept that I need.

Answer (score 1):

If you are attempting to have each component push some sort of data into a shared collection which you then want to render in your layout file, I'd highly recommend instead using a store instead.

If these are static properties, you don't even need a store, just define them in the layout component or in a file you import into layout.

You haven't given enough detail about the actual purpose of what you're trying to do, but the short answer is, no you cannot do what you are attempting to do (collecting components into the parent layout).